# How to query custom posts using a dynamic category

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, templates

I'm not sure if this is possible.. I need help as I am probably asking the wrong questions in Google.

What I need to do is:

Pull CPT 'team' to a CPT 'location' template (I can do this part)

However, each 'location' will have a different team, I realise that I can't code in the category 'Bristol' in the query because then my post template will only show 'Bristol' 'Team'

I need it to be user friendly in the CMS as there might be new locations and teams to add.

Any help in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a category page, you can get the id of the current category by using [get_category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category):

```
 $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
 $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

**EDIT:** You could use the variable `$cat_id` inside your query instead of 'Bristol' and it would pull the correct category for each page.

Comment: I'm not clear on how that would solve it? I can see that I can make a category page - I'm not sure how I connect that up and still be able to let users edit in the CMS. If you can explain a bit more please, that would be great.

Comment: I think it might have clicked  - so I query the category, and then get the content related to that category in another query?

Comment: Cheers for the edit - makes sense, appreciated :)